# generate new input fields from button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to generate a set of input boxes from the click of a button. I pretty much just need them to be clones of the original input boxes in my example code along with the text before hand; Angle and Magnitude.
From the `submit_angle_button` I must then be able to retrieve in the information within all the input boxes. Let me know if you need anymore information. 
**HTML**

```
<div id="angleWrapper">
    <label>Add angled force</label><br>
    <form>
        Angle:<input type="text" id="userAngle" maxlength="3">
        Magnitude:<input type="text" id="userMagnitude" maxlength="2">
        <button id="add_button">Add</button><br>
        <button id="submit_angle_button">Enter</button> 
    </form> 
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#add_button").click(function(){
        //code to create and display new text box
    });
    $("#submit_angle_button").click(function(){
        getInputs(); //Function that takes the values of all text boxes
    });
});
```

EDIT: I must be able to access the new input box's information separately from the first set of boxes, and since I want to generate more than one set of input boxes, the id would probably need to be categorised. For example id="1_userAngle" id="2_userAngle" etc

Comment: Don't see why I got so many downvotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/jg4mbpnf/2/) I dynamically add HTML to the `DOM` by the `.on` function in jQuery. Then when the user clicks the `submit_angle_button` button I gather all of the data in each element in a array. The ending result being an array of angles and an array of magnitudes.

Comment: Brilliant solution, although i don't understand some things I will have to dissect it and learn from it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div id="angleWrapper">
    <label>Add angled force</label><br>
    <form>
        Angle:<input type="text" id="userAngle" maxlength="3">
        Magnitude:<input type="text" id="userMagnitude" maxlength="2">
            <div id="target_div"></div>
            <button id="add_button">Add</button><br>
            <button id="submit_angle_button">Enter</button> 
        </form> 

</div>
```

JavaScript

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#add_button").click(function(){
            var inner_html = 'Angle:<input type="text" id="userAngle" maxlength="3">'
            +'Magnitude:<input type="text" id="userMagnitude" maxlength="2">';
             $("#target_div").append(inner_html);
        });
        $("#submit_angle_button").click(function(){
            getInputs(); //Function that takes the values of all text boxes
        });
    });

    function getInputs()
    {
    $(input).each(function(){ console.log($(this).val()) });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$("#add_button").click(function(){
    $('<input type="text"/>').appendTo('form');
});
```